# Specific empty children classes

Tags: object-oriented-design

Is having empty children classes, just to specify, a bad practice?

Lets suppose I've a generic Product class. There are electrical, electronic and mechanical products. I need to represent all them and must be able to differ each one in some operations.
I've two options:

- add a member named "type" in Product class to specify whether it's a electrical, electronic or mechanical product.
- create children classes of Product, one for each kind of product: ElectricalProduct, ElectronicProduct and MechanicalProduct. As these classes don't differ from each other in methods or members - already defined in parent class - they would be all empty.

I consider second option a better approach, but is it the right way? I've never seen such thing on any application or library.

What do you thing? Any suggestion?

*Edit:*

Here is an example of doing it using second option: https://gist.github.com/tsouzar/c2ffebbcdad30920bf06

I can't see a better way of doing it, but I don't know if it is a good practice to have that empty classes.

Comment: Tiago, could you provide an example of at least one operation in which your treatment of products differ?  It would help in offering solutions.  Otherwise there is too much guesswork involved on both sides.

Comment: In particular, it is puzzling why, according to your comments, you say that the first option will cause you *"to add so much ifs in the code"* but the second will not, yet you also say that **a)** Product contains no logic and **b)** the second option would have classes with no added code at all, differing from Product only by class name.  If **a** and **b** are true then there is no real difference between your two options; both require some other code to check the type and act differently according to the result.

Comment: @itsbruce there is no difference between each type of product. They're exactly equals, with same members and same methods (getters and setters).
When I said it will cause me _to add so much `if`s in the code_, I'm saying about to use Product class somewhere. Having different classes for each kind of product I would be able to simply do method overloading, whereas "type" member would need to be checked using `if`s (as less they appear in code, better).

Comment: So you would be using method overloading in some product management/dispatch class to have it behave differently depending on the subclass passed to it. OK.

Comment: Only reason I need to differ one type of product from another is that at some part of my application it's need to have them in a defined order (e.g.: 1st electrical products, 2nd electronics and 3rd mechanical ones), perhaps in 3 separated vectors.

Comment: So you suggest me to implement second option, even it will lead me to have empty classes?

Comment: Will type up my answer this evening.

Comment: If you use classes, then what will you do once you also have some other product classifications (say large/small and heavy/light)? Will you have `SmallLightElectronicProduct` and `SmallHeavyElectronicProduct` and `LargeLightElectronicProduct` and `LargeHeavyElectronicProduct` and `SmallLightMechanicalProduct` and ...?

Comment: Unrelated: is `std::string*` necessary?

Comment: @immibis I'm not an expert in C++, but I don't see any reason to copy objects which will be available during all running time of application, so I prefer to just point them. Maybe referencing would be even better.

Comment: And, although I would never create so specific classes, this is actually a problem. Fortunately @itsbruce showed me a better approach (using map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've explained more fully, it seems that there really is no subclass-specific logic.  In that case, inheritance is *not* the right choice.  If there really are only minor ways in which other parts of the code treat products, putting code into product classes would be wrong - a violation of separation of concerns which would encumber the product classes with knowledge of other parts of your system.  The sorting example makes that clear. Products should not know how they are sorted or stored or presented; if the code which sorts or presents objects is changed, the product class should not need to be rewritten.

I apologise for doubting you on that.  We see so many people here presenting questions which are based on poor OO knowledge and I assumed this was the case when I should have asked for more info first.

**In fact...**

The method overloading choice, as shown in your example code, is actually going against principles like the separation of concerns and DRY.  What is the common thing about the  **add_product** method?  It adds a product to the appropriate collection.  But in the example code, that single, fundamentally identical task is duplicated in three different places.  This is really scarcely different to a chain of **if..then..else** logic.

- The logic is duplicated and any changes to the common behaviour will have to be duplicated in each place.  Mistakes are likely and will go undetected.
- The product-adding code *should not need* to know what types of products are available.  All it needs to know is that there are a variety of products, each of which should be added to an appropriate collection.  Making it aware means you have to change this section of the code every time you add a new product.

A better way to do this, if you really do need a separate collection for each type of product, would be to have a map of product collections.  The key would be the product type.  Then you could have one single **product_add** method, which consults that map and adds the product to the right place.  Even if you discovered that there *is* some need for different product subclasses, this method doesn't need to know.  The object class itself could be the key to the map, for example.

Since more than one method is likely to want to update or read from those collections, it is probably better to have a **Products** object which stores the objects.  Whether it contains a map of *N* different collections or one collection which it knows how to filter/search by type is an implementation detail which need not concern other parts of your code.

**In Summary**

Since there really seems to be no product-specific code, extra empty classes are not only useless, they complicated your code and make it more fragile.  A 'type' member is better.

- *Most* of your code doesn't even need to know that there is such a member.
- In each domain (the clearly separate sections of your application), identify those few bits which genuinely need to differentiate between product types.
- Isolate them in special helper classes or functions which will return the appropriate product (or do the appropriate thing which matches the type)
- Maps are very useful (they can contain not only collections but other helper objects/functions to hand back to some other code to do the appropriate thing with this object) but should be hidden from anything but the privileged code which really needs to be product-type aware.

If you do that, not only will your code be cleaner and more elegant (free from ugly **if..then..else** chains, for one thing), if you ever do find a real need for product subclasses, almost none of your existing code will have to change.  And even they need only change their internal implementation, because their code will *still* be no concern of the product class or any of its subclasses.

There is still plenty of fun to be had with adding new classes in the respective domains to encapsulate any "I know what kind of products there are".  One challenge is differentiating between the bits of those code which are domain specific (e.g. sorting in a collection which is only relevant in one domain) from those which are actually general.  The list of all valid product types, for example, should be an **enum** which can be fetched by any product-aware domain-specific code.  Any map should use that enum as the *type* for its key.  Any function which takes a product "type" as a parameter should take a parameter only of that enum type and so on. Now, where in your code are you going to define that enum?

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer. Everything you said makes sense and indeed using map is a nice approach - although less performance friendly. Your suggestion for **Products** would be like **products_manager** in my example code?

Comment: I'm not sure I did understand your last affirmation.

Comment: The whole last paragraph?  Or the last line or so?  Give me an idea of the part that is not clear and I will reword it.

Comment: Last lines, starting from "...any function which returns..."

Comment: Edited for some more clarity, I hop.

Comment: Thanks, now it's comprehensive. I would put enums in its own header file and include it in `products_manager` header.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason you are having trouble with which path to take is because there is a fundamental design flaw here. You have [anemic classes](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) here, which is itself an OO anti-pattern. The external logic that is switching on the type needs to be brought into the `Product` family of classes.

The code smell for this is that, no matter which path you go, you will either need to check a type member or `instanceof` in other places in your code. The other smell is that you will constantly be querying a `Product` object for data and making decisions based on it (see [tell-don't-ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)). This means that it will be difficult to modify or add behavior because you will be needing to make changes in many, disparate places rather than in an appropriate class to hold that behavior for each type.

**Edit:**

The addition of the code details shows there is a little more nuance to your question. Let's start by looking at what we are talking about by "type" of product.

Traditionally, anytime we hear the word "type", we jump to the object concept of Type (which I will capitalize to differentiate). This Type is associated with polymorphic behavior, inheritance, encapsulation, and all the other object-oriented concepts. Here, though, we aren't necessarily describing a Type. We are talking about what looks to be a data attribute called a type. The *behavior* does not really change based on the type, only the *value*.

As an example to compare against, we can look at integers. We have `int`s `1` and `2`. The behaviors between them are exactly the same; only the values differ. This means that we shouldn't have an abstract type for `int` that is implemented as a `int1` concrete type and an `int2` concrete type, etc. We need one concrete type for all `int`s, and a simple way to interact between them (like comparison for sorting). Your idea of a product type is the same.

If your products **have or will have** distinct, polymorphic behaviors, inheritance is a valid solution. Here, though, your type is only a data attribute, like the price and the brand, with no difference in behavior. Therefore, you should have a type attribute like you have a price attribute and a brand attribute.

Ideally, you will want to make your code more open-closed, so there should be a way to do this as elegantly as possible. We can create an enum containing the different types of products that exist, ordered in the order they need to be output (using a static std::set or similar on `product` might be easier to work with, if you'd rather). The type attribute of the `product` will point to an enum value. In your `product_manager` class, instead of three named vectors, you should have a map/dictionary-type structure to map from type enum to the respective vector, generated from the elements in the enum. This way, that structure will automatically add vectors for each type at instantiation. When you add a product, select the vector to add it to based on the type of the product. Then you can iterate over the map, then over each vector to print out the products, grouped by type.

*Pseudocode:*

```
enum product_type { electrical, electronic, mechanical }

class product {
    //...

    get_type() {
        return this.type;
    }

    //...
}

class product_manager {
    map<product_type, vector<product>> products;

    product_manager() {
        foreach(p_type in product_type) {
            products.insert(p_type, new vector<product>);
        }
    }

    //...

    add_product(product p) {
        products.at(p.get_type()).append(p);
    }

    //...

    print_products() {
        foreach(p_type in product_type) {
            foreach(product in products.at(p_type)) {
                print_product(product);
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

If you never want to use the type anywhere else, you can make it private, and make the `product_manager` a friend to `product`.

---

I also want to make a quick point about the example code you posted.

> ```
> //in real application we don't know instantiation proccess, so don't know what type of product comes to us.
> test::electrical_product *ep = new test::electrical_product;
> test::electronic_product *etp = new test::electronic_product;
> test::mechanical_product *mp = new test::mechanical_product;
>
> // set products' members values
>
> pm.add_product(ep);
> pm.add_product(etp);
> pm.add_product(mp);
>
> pm.print_electrical_products();
> pm.print_electronic_products();
> pm.print_mechanical_products();
> ```

You use method overloading with different parameter types to determine which implementation to call. The trouble with this is that, in your real application, all the products would be of type `abstract_product *`. The compiler routes the method calls based on the **compile-time type** of the object, meaning any products being added would be sent to a method `product_manager.add_product(abstract_product *)` instead of the overloaded methods, meaning that it would not do what you intend.

Comment: So I should use `structs` (C++) instead of classes having only members and it's getters and setters? I need to have application data somewhere.

You're thinking in PHP. In C++ I could use method overloading to do specific operations without even write an `if`.

Comment: According to you last phrase, it sounds you prefer/agree with second path.

Comment: I don't think Fowler's opinion is a widely held one. Moving logic into a domain model is sometimes at odds with separation of concerns. The OP mentions ordering which is a nice example - products don't have an obvious natural order, so IMO ordering logic should live in a separate class, closer to the presentation layer.

Comment: @Daniel The original answer was written before the code context was provided. I think my answer is still on the right track, but needs more nuance and explanation in the context of the code provided. I am currently ruminating on how to provide just that nuance and explanation. Thanks for your input, though, as I find myself agreeing with some of the points you made.

Comment: Great solution, @cbojar. Thanks for `std::map` suggestion as I'm not familiar with STL. I just don't like your `product_manager`'s `print_product()` because that way I can't choose where and when to print only products of a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that adding a type member is a better solution. It's simpler to define, allows you to treat the type as a first-class value, lets you code Product as a plain old data structure (which it is), works without RTTI, and you can use a `switch` instead of multiple `if`/`else` to efficiently branch based on the type. Using inheritance your code can break if someone introduces a new subclass, since you're only expecting a finite number of types of products.

Comment: I learned while programming in PHP to don't use conditionals to check type of an object. There is a whole movement against using conditionals (mainly `if`) to do things that are possible to do by using features of object orientation. By using "type" member I would need to check it mostly every time to do same thing as in code I provided as example (need to have distinct vectors for each product type).

Comment: I agree with your last statement. I don't know anymore which approach is less worse, both them have multiple problems.

Comment: @Tiago.SR Don't use OO features for the sake of using OO features. There *is* a reason why type testing is frowned upon, but no matter which solution you pick you're going to be testing the type. The fact that it's superficially more object-oriented (it really isn't) isn't a valid reason to use the inheritance implementation; that's just cargo cult programming. As far as I can tell, the inheritance solution is objectively worse in almost every way.

Comment: Doval is right here, @Tiago.SR .  Even a switch isn't needed in most cases.  It should be possible for most of your code not to be aware of the different product types, simply aware that there *are* different types, if you provide ways to to look up the appropriate thing to do (or corresponding thing to fetch).  Maps can be good for this.  Writing this up now in my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's best to have one `Product` class with a type field, for a few reasons:

- If you ever need to serialize/deserialize in a way that the language doesn't natively support, there's only one constructor; you don't need to switch on the type and use one of several constructors.
- There's a slight benefit to readability - if readers see `ElectricalProduct` they might wonder if it contains special logic, and have to open it to see that it doesn't.
- You can make `Product` final (Java) or sealed (C#), which is good for efficiency - certain method invocations won't need to go through a vtable.

That said, if you think you might later add some logic specific to certain product types, then separate classes might be better so that you can do so without a major refactor.

Comment: Just no.  Tiago is clearly not familiar with basic OO principles and has one class loaded with all the code necessary to deal with each different type of product.  That's a basic design mistake, both of the options he lists are bad extensions of that mistake and you're just endorsing that.

Comment: @itsbruce I'm pretty familiar with SOLID, DRY, KISS and whatever. Product is an entity, **it has no logic**, only getters and setters to members commons to every kind of product.

Comment: If you have different logic for different types, then you are wrong about at least some of that, Tiago.  At the very least, as you have described it, the strategies to deal with particular stages of the lifecycle of a product differ.  The place to put those strategies is not in a super class.  They might be added into a product object via composition, perhaps.

Comment: So I'm not wrong, I've never said there are different logic, but the opposite. Every product kind have same members and same methods (getters and setters only) doing exactly the same thing. In order to avoid code repetition, I need to centralize them in some [parent] class, but this leads me to create empty classes. Alternative is to have a "type" member, but this leads me to add so much `if`s in the code where I'll use these entity classes. Which is worst?

Comment: Both are wrong.  You are wrong to think you only have those two options.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions (separate answer).

Comment: @Tiago:I think what bruce is trying to say is that classes are supposed to have data AND BEHAVIOR. Yours do not have behavior so they aren't and shouldn't be classes. Furthermore, you want to inherit these classes from a "class" that also isn't really a class. Once again, no behavior. Thus, the "clearly not familiar with basic OO principles" comment. You want ideas. The problem is that you have framed your problem to be to data centric/low-level so you'll always have a "but" in response. To do a proper OO design we'd need to know the big picture problem you are trying to create a solution for.

Comment: @Dunk say we're building a website which simply stores products in memory and provides pages for creating, viewing and editing products. We won't have any interesting product-related logic, but don't you think a Product class would be useful and appropriate? If you feel it's bad to have classes with no behavior, what would you do instead?

Answer (score -1):

If indeed you *"must be able to differ each one in some operations"*
as you say, introducing three such intermediate classes is a perfectly
sensible idea.

Have a look at the idea of **Abstract Class** (e.g. [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)).
An abstract class cannot be instantiated itself (most OO languages
have a respective construct that will technically
forbid instantiation) but it provides variables and methods
to its children -- and each child class still needs to add some bit
to make a complete, instantiable class.

In your case, ElectricalProduct, ElectronicProduct and MechanicalProduct
would be abstract classes.

Comment: You mean they should be concrete classes and product should be abstract?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but sounds like you overlooked this clarification - "Only reason I need to differ one type of product from another is that at some part of my application it's need to have them in a defined order".

Comment: I know Abstract Class from PHP, but is the same as in Java.
I'm reading in other places people asking same thing as I am now, but specifically in Java environment. It appears Java programmers agree with having empty classes whereas those from other programming languages don't. I'm more confused than ever, even more because there are here answers saying different things.

Comment: My answer assumed that your "must be able to differ in some operations" meant that, over time, code would be added _to these classes_ that needs to be different for each of them and that there are subclasses for each of them (or else the 3 should be concrete classes, not abstract). If you don't expect to have such code, have a look at [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) and reconsider. If you still don't expect to have such code, then my suggestion is not the right one for you. Sorry for the confusion then.